# Extracting date from the format

Tags: c++, caa

I am struggling through this date extraction. I have a date like this 
`("D("yyyy-mm-dd"))`.
I want to get this `"yyyy-mm-dd"` and I cannot strip `("D(")` this also because I have this format in other places so I tried like this 
 first searching the string but I am not sure if I am on right track
eg. `intabc = istrdate.SearchSubString("D(");`
so please suggest how can I get this value.

Input is
`"(D(YYYY-MM-DD))"` 
OUTPUT that I want 
`(YYYY-MM-DD)`

What i have done(not correct way I think )
intabc = istrdate.SearchSubString("D(");

Comment: Please show your failing code.

Comment: Could you add some examples of input and expected output?

Comment: You might use [strptime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) if your system has it. Otherwise your question is C++ standard specific (C++11 has [`<string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string) and [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono)... but older C++ don't) and/or OS specific. Read also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) at least to understand that time and date is a tricky subject.

Comment: Without more details and without [MCVE] your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `substr()` and `string::erase()` functions in c++98

```
string str = "\"D(\"yyyy-mm-dd\")";
string result = str.substr(3);  
result.erase(result.end() - 1)
result.erase(result.end() - 1)
```

if you are using c++11 you can also use `string::pop_back()` method.

Comment: I did like this that is from 2nd place I want 11 characters subString(2,11);